# Oracle Fusion Middleware Encryption / Decryption Sensitive Payload Data

Tags: oracle-adf

Does anyone know of a encryption / decryption technique for sensitive data in a message payload to prevent the information from showing up in audit logs? For example, a payload containing a password. The password should not appear in any logs. When the payload is received, the password needs to be encrypted and then just before the payload is forwarded the password needs to be decrypted. I'm looking for a generic solution that will work with OSB and BPEL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was in the Oracle code examples all along. See bpel-310 Partial Message encryption

https://java.net/projects/oraclesoasuite11g/pages/BPEL

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an Encryption/Decryption Web Service and use it in BPEL, OSB and you ADF application if you want, there are many Encryption Algorithms with this solution you should be able to choose what you want to use.